# Invitation link implementation .NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I`m developing .NET Web API pet application, that uses JWT authentication.

It has private rooms(lets say lobbies), so users don't have access to the list of them.

The idea is to create invitation link like `https://mycoolapp.com/Room/sd1Fds/join=token`,
so unauthorized user can click it and join room after he logs in.

The idea comes from discord invitation link
[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpgh.jpg)

I want it to have expiration time, so user can choose between 3,5,7 hours for example.
[Discord implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxXh2.jpg)

The question is, how should I implement it, I`m currently looking at` SecurityToken` class, is that right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the `SecurityToken` is a good point to start

you can create a room and generate a unique id (GUID) for that. then create a JWT token and include the generated unique id as a claim into it. then generate the invitation link including the JWT token and send it to guest

after the guest clicks on the link, redirect to the login page and then redirect to the API with the JWT token included in the query string. in the endpoint that handles the invitation link, check if everything is ok and the id exists as a claim, and the expiration time is ok, grant the user access to the private room

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle and just generated some random unique id (`Guid.NewGuid` can be sufficient) and stored it in the database with additional information (like expiration date, invited person ids, etc.) and on join attempt validated that link against the stored data (link has not expired, person attempting to join is in the list, etc.).

Comment: this should be an accepted answer. first make sure the user is logged in by validating their JWT (.net provides excellent middleware out of the box for this). This way you can put [Authorized] attribute on endpoint that checks the rooms so not just anyone can scan them. Then make sure the room actually exists, invitation hasnt expired, user is not blacklisted, etc. Associate their ID/email to the room. later if he needs to be kicked out blacklist his ID.